# TinyMCE: Possible to disallowing specified values in given attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tinymce

I want to add a rule where i set "position:absolute" inside the style attribute to invalid. I can set tags and attributes to invalid using invalid_elements or valid_elements (see link)..

This has to be disallowed trough the source_editor ("code" button) and paste plugin

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:Cleanup/Output

The problem is that people are "hacking" the css/xhtml ending up putting a absolute positoned div covering the entire page..

How could this be prevented? Is there any built in functionality in TinyMCE, or could it be achieved trough JS/jQuery and RegEx? (I use the jQuery version of TinyMCE)

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify [invalid attributes, only elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainvalid_elements).

Anything the user does on their side can not be trusted.  You must sanitize the input on the server side.

You could do a simple regex like:

```
$data = preg_replace('/position\s*:\s*\w+;?/','',$data);
```